# Why is given example not in 3NF?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

I have following example which I am trying to understand, where:

```
R = {A, B, C}
FD = {A->B, B->C, AB->C}
```

Prime key is `A`.

I know that this example is in 2NF, because prime key has only one element, but I dont understand why this example is not in 3NF.

C is functionaly dependent on AB, but B is not a key or part of an key. Is that the reason why it is not in the 3NF.

Thanks

Comment: *C is functionally dependent on AB, but B is not a key or part of an key.*  And that's why it's not 3rd normal form.  In 3rd normal form, the entity is dependent on the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me Codd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Relation R, the canonical cover of the set of dependencies FD is:

```
1. A → B
2. B → C
```

The reason is that the dependency `A B → C` can be derived from the others:

```
1. A → B  (given)
2. AB → B (by enrichment of A → B)
3. AB → C (by transitivity of AB → B and B → C)
```

A candidate key of the relation is `A`, since its closure determines all the other attributes:

```
A+ = A
A+ = AB (by using A → B)
A+ = ABC (by using B → C)
```

No other attribute can be a key (`B` cannot determine `A`, `C` appear only on the rigth part of a dependency).

Remember that a schema is in Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF) if and only if all the determinants of the functional dependencies of the canonical cover are superkeys, or, for the Third Normal Form (3NF), if and only if all the determinants of the functional dependencies of the canonical cover are superkeys, or a determinate is a prime attribute.

So, the schema is not in BCNF, neither in 3NF, since there is the functional dependency `B → C` in which the determinant `B` is not a key, and `C` is not a prime attribute. Finally, decomposing the schema in two relations:

```
R1 < (A B), { A → B } >

R2 < (B C), { B → C } >
```

we have two relations that are both in 3NF and in BCNF, and this decomposition preserves the functional dependencies of the original schema.